# How to clear TimeZoneInfo cache in WinRT?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, timezone, uwp

In .NET some values used by `TimeZoneInfo` are cached, such as the current time zone in use by `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, `DateTime.ToLocalTime`, etc.  In traditional .NET framework apps, this cache can be cleared by calling `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`, as [explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata).

However, in WinRT applications, such as Windows Store apps, and Windows Universal Apps, the `ClearCachedData` API is not available.

How do you clear the time zone cache in a WinRT environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an undocumented way to achieve this, [as seen here in the .NET reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,733).

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(0), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

This will clear the time zone cache, and it works in WinRT as well as traditional .NET Framework (4.6+), .NET Core, and PCL.

According to my colleagues at Microsoft on the .NET team, this is an unofficial workaround to a known problem.  It is not expected to be removed, but it is an implementation detail and not part of the public API, so use at your own risk.

Note that `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData` should be used instead of this approach, when it is available.  It was added to .NET Standard 2.0, and UWP 10.1  ([see all environments here](https://apisof.net/catalog/723322fa-a530-e7f7-81f3-7cdd850c84cf)).