# DateTime.Now vs system time

Tags: c#, .net, windows, time

Let's imagine that this little program runs:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} -> {DateTime.Now} tz={TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName} / {TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName}");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

When I change the system's time zone when the program is running the app does not see the change. The timezone and the time is as if the timezone has not changed.

In order for the app to display the new time and time zone I need to restart the app.

If I change the system time the time change is picked up immediately.

It would be great if you could help me with three questions:

- is this documented anywhere?
- why isn't the timezone change picked up while the application is running?
- can I do anything so that the app picks up timezone changes while it's running?

Here's a little screenshot to show the .NET app using time different than the operating system:
[image: .NET App out of sync with system time.]

BTW. On Windows IOT on Raspberry Pi, my experiment shows that if I restart the app it will show the new timezone, but the 'old' time. The new time will be picked up after restarting the the system.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can check the following msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone(v=vs.110).aspx). It clearly states the following :

> Notes to Callers: Local time zone data is cached after CurrentTimeZone
>   is first used to retrieve time zone information. If the system's local
>   time zone subsequently changes, the CurrentTimeZone property does not
>   reflect this change. If you need to handle time zone changes while
>   your application is running, use the TimeZoneInfo class and call its
>   TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData method.

**is this documented anywhere?**
Yes, as stated above.

**why isn't the timezone change picked up while the application is running?**
Because the timezone information is cached.

**can I do anything so that the app picks up timezone changes while it's running?**
Yes, by using the TimeZoneInfo class and calling its TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData method.

Comment: Do you also know how to achieve what TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData does in Universal Windows? The method is not available.

Comment: In Universal Windows you need to call this method via Reflection (and test it works on your device) - it has been made private

Comment: @mayu there is a workaround, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300091/1469494)