# TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData not in Universal Windows

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

This is a follow up question to [DateTime.Now vs system time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899112/datetime-now-vs-system-time)

In normal `.NET TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` is available to sync the application the system timezone.

In Universal Windows version of `TimeZoneInfo` this method is not present.

Can I somehow sync the timezone info?

Comment: Did you verify that it actually caches timezone in UWP too?

Comment: Just don't. Use DateTimeOffset at least, instead of assuming that the systems uses this or that timezone. Also remember that an RPi doesn't have a battery-backed real-time clock. It will *lose* the current time when it restarts and synchronize with a time server

Comment: @Evk Yes, I verified.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I get the current local time in RPi? :/

Comment: A quick fix is to use `UtcNow` instead of `Now` to get the UTC time, not the local time. You'd have to ensure you use and *store* UTC time throughout your application. That's why using DateTimeOffset is easier

Comment: @mayou the same as every other system. The problem is that *you* changed the local timezone in your code. Any local DateTime value you retrieved before the change, will reflect the *old* timezone and that's it. Use `DateTimeOffset.Now` instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm confused, using DateTimeOffset.Now doesn't change anything. DateTimeOffset also uses the cached version of timezone information so if the the TZ changes  it will produce time that's incorrect.

Comment: No it won't. It will return the correct time for the offset it contains. That correct time can be converted to any other offset by calling to [ToOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tooffset(v=vs.110).aspx). You can display the same DateTimeOffset value converted to 5 different offsets if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148360/discussion-between-mayu-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300091/1469494) for a neat workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
using System.Reflection;

MethodInfo clearCachedData = typeof(TimeZoneInfo).GetMethod("ClearCachedData", 
   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
if (clearCachedData != null)
{
    clearCachedData.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Tested on:

- Device Model:     Raspberry Pi 3
- OS Version:   10.0.14393.0

**Solution 2**

[How to clear TimeZoneInfo cache in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300083/how-to-clear-timezoneinfo-cache-in-winrt/34300091#34300091)