# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime is incredibly slow on DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I just noticed that one of our unit tests was taking up ten seconds. After playing around with it, I've created a minimum linqpad example to reproduce it:

```
void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    {
      //var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZone);   
      var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.MinValue, timeZone);   
    }
    sw.Stop();
    (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms").Dump();
}
```

This takes 40 seconds on my PC or our build PC. If I use DateTime.UtcNow, it takes 15 ms.

Any reason why or workarounds for this?

---

Edit: as suggested in the comments, I decompiled TimeZoneInfo and there is a special case on DateTime.MinValue:

```
static public DateTime ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) {
    // Special case to give a way clearing the cache without exposing ClearCachedData()
    if (dateTime.Ticks == 0) {
        ClearCachedData();
    }
```

Looks like (test?) code that clears the cache each time it's called with a DateTime.MinValue.

Leaves the question why this happens.

Comment: I guess you could use some Dll decompilation tool to check the code your self and see how each of the two properties are generated behind the scenes.

Comment: Good point, I'll take a look.

Comment: `// Special case to give a way clearing the cache without exposing ClearCachedData()`  Well, that's kinda evil.  Especially so since it is actually exposed.  That got past a code review, somehow.  Luckily converting an ancient date from Bethlehem is not that common :)

Comment: The reason we had a lot of hits is that DateTime.MinValue is the default value, it's the same as using new DateTime().

Comment: It is fairly stunning how often a "magic value" goes wrong.  But yes, often by more than one programmer thinking it is magic enough.  Always favor `Nullable<DateTime>` here.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to decompile.  You can find this in [the .NET Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,727), or in [the CoreCLR source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/66b31aab41996565ef02893cfdf12db485b7c07d/src/mscorlib/src/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs#L617-L635).

The special case was added in .NET 4.6 as an unofficial workaround to clearing the time zone cache in environments such as WinRT that did not have the `ClearCachedData` method exposed at the time.  [I describe this further here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34300083/634824).

Occasionally clearing the time zone cache doesn't usually have a noticeable effect.  You're seeing it because of the tight loop.  If that's a concern for your use case, then I suggest using either the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method, or the versions of `ConvertTime` that work with `DateTimeOffset`.  Those code paths do not hit the special case.

Yes, I agree this should be documented better.  I'll see if I can get that in.

Note that logically, converting time zones for `DateTime.MinValue` doesn't have much meaning, as time zones as we know them today were not around in year 1.

Comment: Our production servers CPU's were peaking a few months ago. Checking what the threads were doing, all were busy with TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime. We could not figure out why. So this should at least be documented in the MSDN info. We'll change our calls to ConvertTimeFromUtc and take a look at why we're calling with DateTime.MinValue. Thanks for the info.